# How to enable PDO on a server with very limited access?

Tags: php, iis, pdo, iis-6, php-5.2

I want to run a website on a server (actually only part of the server) I have a very limited access to. The only two things I can do is to connect via FTP to my part in the server and to connect to one MySQL database.

On this server I want to run some PHP code which uses PDO. The problem is that PDO is not enabled on this server.

So what can I do to have PDO on this server with the access I have?

Some more information on the server: It is a Windows server which runs Microsoft IIS 6.0. It has PHP 5.2.3.

Comment: contact the server owner, and ask them to install the appropriate extension

Comment: PHP 5.2 had its [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php) over 2 years ago! Switch servers immediately.

Comment: I know, I'm trying to switch but it's not as easy as it looks...

Comment: @Cokegod on the site I linked to has a link to articles about migrating to newer versions of PHP.

Comment: Or perhaps you could try to convince the server admins to upgrade their PHP to something more modern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PDO isn't enabled (check `<? phpinfo(); ?>`) there's not much you can do... It can't be enabled without access to the PHP configuration on server level.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean: permissions?

When you connect the database with pdo, then you set the user. If in the phpmyadmin create the user with low permissions, then you can connect with this user in php pdo.

Example, if you created the user name of: readonly, and set readonly user password and permissions, then in connection you can use this user and password.

Sry for my english!